# Need help solving these limits

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

$$1. \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{2n^2 + 5}{1 + 5 + ... + (4n - 3)} + \frac{5}{n}\right)$$
$$2. \lim_{x \to -1} \left(\frac{x^4 + 2x^3 + 4x^2 + 6x + 3}{x^3 - 3x^2 - 9x - 5}\right)$$
$$3. \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{x-1}{14x+5}\right)^{1-3x}$$
$$4. \lim_{x \to 0} (1+\sin{(7x)})^{(\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}5]{1-9x+x^2}-1)^{-2}}$$
$$5. \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x \cdot \ln(1+4x^2)}{(1-2x^3)^8-1}$$

Comment: Please show what you have done to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINTS:

- 1)

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2n^2+5}{1+5+\dots+(4n-3)}+\frac{5}{n}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2n^2+5}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(4k-3)}+\frac{5}{n}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2n^2+5}{2n^2-n}+\frac{5}{n}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2+5}{2n^2-n}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5}{n}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2+5}{2n^2-n}+0=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2+5}{2n^2-n}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2+\frac{5}{n^2}}{2-\frac{1}{n}}=$$
$$\frac{2+0}{2-0}=\frac{2}{2}=1$$

- 2)
  $$\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{x^4+2x^3+4x^2+6x+3}{x^3-3x^2-9x-5}=\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{x^2+3}{x-5}=\frac{(-1)^2+3}{(-1)-5}=-\frac{2}{3}$$
- 3)
  $$\text{L}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x-1}{14x+5}\right)^{1-3x}=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-3x)\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{14x+5}\right)\right)$$

$$\text{so when}\space\space x\to\infty\space\space\text{then}\space\space\text{L}\to\infty$$

- 4) Notice: a two-sided limit does not exist!

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\left(1+\sin(7x)\right)^{\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt[5]{x^2-9x+1}-1\right)^2}}=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\ln(1+\sin(7x))}{\left(\sqrt[5]{x^2-9x+1}-1\right)^2}\right)=0$$

Comment: Can you explain how you get $$\frac{x^2+3}{x-5}$$ from the original expression? Are you dividing these polynomials?

Comment: $$\frac{x^4+2x^3+4x^2+6x+3}{x^3-3x^2-9x-5}=$$
$$\frac{(x^2+2x+1)(x^2+3)}{(x^2+2x+1)(x-5)}=$$
Cancel terms, assuming $x^2+2x+1\ne0$
$$\frac{x^2+2x+1}{x^2+2x+1}\cdot\frac{x^2+3}{x-5}=$$
$$1\cdot\frac{x^2+3}{x-5}=\frac{x^2+3}{x-5}$$

@Alex, you're welcome!

Comment: Thank you, but in fact, i understand that $$(x+1)^2$$ is a root, i don't understand, how to find these multipliers: $$(x^2+3), (x-5)$$

Comment: And, sorry for my stupidity, can you explain one more thing? 
Is that correct? $$\exp(\lim_{x \to \infty} (1-3x) \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(\frac{x-1}{14x+5})) = e^{\lim_{x \to \infty} (1-3x) \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(\frac{x-1}{14x+5})}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: for 1) prove by induction that $$\sum_{i=1}^n 4i-3=2n(n+3)$$
for 2) show that $$\frac{x^4+2x^3+4x^2+6x+3}{x^3-3x^2-9x-5}={\frac {{x}^{2}+3}{-5+x}}$$
for 3) the limit doesn't exist
for 4) the limit doesn't exist
for 5) prove by L'Hospital that the limit is given by $$-\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, but is there any solution for 5th without L'Hopital's rule? I shouldn't use it here by the task condition...